# In jfet voltage divider bias how can Vgs be negative with out knowing the resistor values?

Tags: jfet

With out referring to particular values of the resistors, my textbook states that Vgs in below circuit is negative. How is this possible? If I increase R2, it increases Vgs, right? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JFET is a **depletion** device meaning it is normally on, it will conduct current when \$V_{GS}\$ = 0. Therefore in amplifiers a common way to use an JFET is to bias it with a **negative** \$V_{GS}\$, for example: \$V_{GS}\$ = -2 V so that the drain current \$I_D\$ is such that the JFET behaves in a linear way.

This bias voltage should not be too close to the **pinch off** voltage where the JFET makes the drain current **zero**.

So in the book they **choose** the resistor values such that \$V_{GS}\$ has a negative value. Let's assume that we're going to bias the JFET at \$I_D\$ = 1 mA and that the JFET we're using needs a \$V_{GS}\$ = -2 V for that. If we make then \$R_S\$ = 3 k\$\Omega\$ then there will be 3 V at the source of the JFET. If we then choose \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ such that there's 1 Volt at the gate of the JFET then we get \$V_{GS}\$ = -2 V.

So the \$V_{GS}\$ is negative statement should be: We bias the JFET such that \$V_{GS}\$ has a negative value. It cannot be seen from the circuit itself. I can use the same circuit to make \$V_{GS}\$ = + 2 V but then the JFET might not operate like I want.

Comment: Exactly! that line about "Vgs is negative" tripped me haha. I read it as - "Vgs will be negative no matter what the resistor values are!" You're my hero again! Thank you so much for your awesomeness:))